# How windows handle raw TCP packets without corresponding socket?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, raw-sockets

I'm stuck with some tasks related to TCP sockets under Windows OS so I need to know the mechanism of how Windows handles TCP packets in & out. Please correct me if my understanding below is wrong:

Using WinSock when a TCP client wants to establish TCP connection to certain `IP:port`, `winsock.connect(dest_IP,dest_Port)` is called. Then

1) The WinSock library on the client will create and send a TCP SYN packet to the destination address.

2) When the client receives other peer's reply with SYN-ACK packet, the WinSock object fires an event called "on_connect" for the client application to handle from thereon.

3) The last ACK packet of the protocol is somehow sent to finish the 3-way-handshake (by the WinSock library or by the OS itself - I don't know). Q1: Who sends it?

I wonder what happens under the hood when I craft a raw SYN-packet using winPCap and send it to the peer. If the dest-IP replies with a SYN-ACK packet then:

Q2: How does the OS (windows) handle that SYN-ACK packet without a relevant winsock object bound to it? Will it automatically follow the 3way-handshake to form a TCP connection or simply drop the packet?

Q3: Can I somehow use winPCap (under admin privilege) to prevent the certain packet from being sent by Windows?

Comment: Anyone who is gonna vote this question down please leave a comment with reasons please.

Comment: WinSock does not support TCP over raw sockets. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . Edit your question suitably. I can explain how TCP would behave w.r.t. your two questions if needed.

Comment: @Erobere I did not say that winsock has anything to do with raw socket. I said normally tcp connection is establish using winsock. But the unusual thing I want to clarify is the way Windows handle things behind the scene. Please help me answer the 2 questions and btw quote the wrong part of my question.

Comment: what version of windows do you want to stop the packets being sent on? The mechanism for this changed a lot between XP and Vista.

Comment: @Flexo I am working with windows from XP2 and above.

Answer (score 3):

TCP is a connection-oriented protocol i.e., (a) there is a communication session established between the peers; and (b) the data is sent as a stream which means each packet is received in the same order as it was sent. Because of the connection-oriented property, TCP is a stateful protocol. Each peer maintains a state of the TCP connection based on messages sent and received. For easier understanding, let us the call the peer which `listen`s as the server and the peer that `connect`s as the client.

On the implementation level, the data structure used to maintain the state is Transmission Control Block [(TCB)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793). As soon as a TCP socket is opened, a TCB is created to hold its state. Further, `accept` creates a new TCB for the actual data socket on the server. Below is a state diagram of TCP which describes how states are changed in the TCB. With this one, it becomes clear what happens when unsolicited control packets are sent.

[image: TCP State diagram]

Figure: Tcp state diagram. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via Commons - Src: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

First, your understanding of the 3-way  handshake is right. This is easily verifiable in the state diagram that both TCBs end up on the ESTABLISHED state. Coming to Q1, since a solicited connection was created, the client TCB would be waiting for a SYN+ACK. Once received, the network stack (either on Linux or Windows) automatically responds with ACK. For practical purposes here, you may consider the network stack is part of the OS. Also note that there is hardly any use to give control for the user application to respond for SYN+ACK. Therefore, it is handled by the stack.

To answer Q2, let us again trace the state diagram. Although you have asked it specific to WinSock, the same operations happen on any implementation of TCP for unsolicited SYN. On the server TCB, it assumes the SYN was legitimate and therefore responds with SYN+ACK. However, there are two possible cases on the client here: (a) there is no TCB for that `IP:port` on the client, and (b) the connection is being teared down.

In case (a), notice that the client can create a TCB but will be in state CLOSED. Receiving a SYN+ACK in this state is an unsusal event for which a response is to send a RST (reset) message is sent to actively break the connection. In some implementations, no message is sent leading to time out. The SYN+ACK just times out on the server TCB and state returns to LISTEN. In fact, time out happens when a client is in ESTABLISHED state but suddenly receives an unsolicited SYN+ACK! More such cases are dealt in this [article](http://www.medianet.kent.edu/techreports/TR2005-07-22-tcp-EFSM.pdf); I have pasted the relevant one below.

[image: Unsolicited ACK]

Case (b) can generalized to say that the client TCB is in one of the CLOSE states. If SYN+ACK is received when the client is in FIN_WAIT 1, FIN_WAIT 2 or CLOSE_WAIT, the client responds with a FIN (for FIN_WAIT 1, FIN_WAIT 2) and FIN/ACK (for CLOSE_WAIT). If it is in any other state, the client does not respond and times out.

Answering Q3: it is possible to filter out packets of connections. Typically this is done with a firewall or program like `ipfilter` in Linux where a certain rule can be described to allow/disallow packets. In Windows 7, you can either set [filter lists](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732038.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or also develop an application using the [Windows Filtering Platform APIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your question was that if you can remove only a certain packet, I must say I have not tried to do that, however from MSDN it looks that you can do that.

Other useful references:

http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/debugging-tcp.html

[TCP/IP Illustrated by Stevens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469), http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/reviews/tcpillus.html

Comment: Thanks for your very informative canonical answer. It makes scene of all what I've wonder about the OS's dirty jobs. Up to this point a question that must be asked is:  "Does Windows from XP2 & above allow us to control the state or even create/delete the TCB of certain TCP connection?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a huge security threat? So the answer would be a no. Of course, on Linux based systems you can modify and recompile the stack as you want.

Comment: Well so it's pretty clear that windows doesn't let apps control everything of TCP even in low level programming. I think TCB itself is significant to TCP prorocol only but the rights to modify TCB is not much a security thread. If we need to manually craft a tcpConnection using tcp socket (commonly seen in P2P technique) then TCB would annoy us a lot.

Comment: @Erobere: BTW the terminology "tcp socket" in my question as you edited is a bit confusing me cause googling the keyword "tcp socket" did not give me any clear result about "tcp socket" but about "socket" or "tcp" instead. I wonder if it was an official entity or a type of raw socket?

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon what are you exactly looking for?

Comment: @Erobere: I am jusf familiar with the 2 concepts of winsock & rawSocket. TcpSocket is a strange concept you put in my question but explained nothing in your answer. That confused me.

Comment: @vantrung-cuncon socket are of 3 types: datagram/udp, stream/tcp and raw sockets in any operating system. Each OS has its own implementation of the socket APIs typically conforming to BSD sockets API. Winsock is only one such implementation. I've tried to be as generic as possible in my answer to explain how TCP works on any OS. If you are uncomfortable with the edit, you are free to change it again.

Comment: Yeah thank you! I got it. Using winsock I can easily switch from tcp to udp & vice versa so I thought they are all same type of socket. I did not know that the mechanism behind them are essentially different. Btw my answer doesn't need to be edited again. I just need to say thank you again for all your valuable helps!